# Contact Picker intent returns to the wrong activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm calling a Contact Picker from an activity named AddFriendActivity. Once a contact is picked, it always returns to the MainActivity rather than the calling activity.

I have checked the android manifest and I can't see any tags that would cause it to prefer MainActivity on resumption. I've extracted (what I think is) the relevant code below.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <activity
        android:name="x.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/activity_main_title" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="x.start.StartActivity"
        android:label="@string/start_activity_title"
        android:noHistory="true" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="x.policies.PoliciesActivity"
        android:label="@string/activity_policies_title" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="x" />

    <activity
        android:name="x.AddFriendActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_friend"
        android:parentActivityName="x.friendster.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

**Code for starting the contact picker from AddFriendActivity**

```
    btnContacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent contactpicker = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(contactpicker, 1);
            Log.e("contactpicker", "meh start");
        }
    });
```

Not sure if this is relevant, but here's the **code that calls the AddFriendActivity from a fragment ChatPanel in MainActivity**

```
    btnAddFriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddFriendActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Any idea why this is happening? I've probably missed something simple...

Comment: remove line `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);` from your `OnClickListener` and see if it works.

Comment: Yes that worked. Rather silly of me, but I thought I'd already tried that before. Thanks!
Convert it to an answer so I can mark as answered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove line `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);`

from your `OnClickListener` and see if it works.

Cheers